# XmlAttributeCollection isn't able to get attributes from xml

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I'm using System.Xml to get attributes from my [xml file](http://student.agh.edu.pl/~wysek/task.xml).

It seems that following code which I found somewhere is able to find nodes correctly however it doesn't recognizes attributes (it's weird because I've created this xml files with System.Xml too):

```
DataSet task_data = new DataSet("Root");
adapter.Fill(task_data); // MySqlDataAdapter is being used here
task_data.WriteXml(path, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

So I don't know why any other xml which can be found on the internet works and mine which was created with the same module doesn't...

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

public class Catalog
{
private XmlDocument xmldoc;
private string path = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\task.xml";

public static void Main()
{
    Catalog c = new Catalog();
}

public Catalog()

//Constructor
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(fs);
    DisplayCatalog();
}

// Method for Displaying the catalog

private void DisplayCatalog()
{
    XmlNodeList xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("task");
    Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of catalogs\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
    {
        XmlAttributeCollection xmlattrc = xmlnode[i].Attributes; //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!

        Console.Write(xmlnode[i].FirstChild.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(":\t\t" + xmlnode[i].FirstChild.InnerText);


        Console.Write(xmlnode[i].LastChild.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(":\t" + xmlnode[i].LastChild.InnerText);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Catalog Finished");
}
//end of class
```

}

Comment: What does the xml file look like that you are trying to read? What is the behavior you are seeing, vs what you would expect?

Comment: http://student.agh.edu.pl/~wysek/task.xml This is my xml files and xmlnode[i].Attributes doesn't store any attributes after loading xml even though xml file is valid because it was created by the same module. I would like to get the first and the last attribue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the xml you linked to contins no attributes only nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <task>
    <TaskId>1</TaskId>
    <TaskDelegatorNote>Presentation</TaskDelegatorNote>
    <StartTime>PT10H</StartTime>
    <EndTime>PT13H</EndTime>
    <TaskEndDate>2011-01-02T00:00:00+00:00</TaskEndDate>
    <TaskContractorNote>Done</TaskContractorNote>
    <TaskStatus>3</TaskStatus>
    <LastModification>Me, 2003-05-15 13:48:59</LastModification>
  </task>
  <task>
    <TaskId>2</TaskId>
    <TaskDelegatorNote>It must be done.</TaskDelegatorNote>
    <StartTime>PT10H</StartTime>
    <EndTime>PT13H</EndTime>
    <TaskEndDate>2011-01-02T00:00:00+00:00</TaskEndDate>
    <TaskContractorNote />
    <TaskStatus>2</TaskStatus>
    <LastModification>Admin, 2009-08-04 10:30:49</LastModification>
  </task>
</Root>
```

Here's an xml snippint with a TaskId attribute

```
   <task TaskId = 1>
   </task>
```

To fix this change

```
      Console.Write(xmlattrc[0].Name);
      Console.WriteLine(":\t\t" + xmlattrc[0].Value);
```

to

```
        Console.Write(xmlnode[0].ChildNodes[0].Name);
        Console.WriteLine(":\t\t" + xmlnode[0].ChildNodes[0].Value);
```

Your output would be

```
Here is the list of catalogs


TaskId:
TaskId:         1
LastModification:       Me, 2003-05-15 13:48:59

TaskId:
TaskId:         2
LastModification:       Admin, 2009-08-04 10:30:49

Catalog Finished
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Also you should look at [LinqToXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for some other ways of doing projections of your xml nodes